# How do I model a Sailor Moon style "hair Meatball" using only geometry?

Tags: hair, geometry, 3d-printing

I'm making a model in Blender that I'm going to 3D print. So everything needs to be done in geometry, or in a form that can be converted into geometry. rather than using an effects plugin.

I want my character to have sailor moon style "meatball" buns on the side of their head, but I'm having trouble making something that looks good.

[image]

I want something the looks like the meatball in the picture below, but with fewer - more pronounced - strands of hair so that they are easy to paint and highlight. What techniques could I try to make this effect?

I only need the meatball, the rest is not a problem.

At the scale that I plan to print, the meatball would be about 1cm diameter.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: There was a boilerplate at the top of my question suggesting that I do exactly this. Presumably one of the admins put it there. The question was closed so nobody could answer it. I wasn't really left with many other options.

Answer (score 2):

Here is something that looks a bit like, and as it's only 1 cm...

You could create a *UV Sphere* with a lot of *Rings* (the amount depending on the printer capacity I guess), duplicate to have a *Shrinkwrap* target, hide the second sphere, back to the first one, select some edges, enable the *Proportional Editing* option, scale or rotate or move to tweak the edges, as the *Shrinkwrap* is on, it keeps a spherical shape:

[image]

Apply the *Shrinkwrap*, select one ring out of 2 with the *Ring Select + Checker Desselect + Select Edge Loops* method, scale except on Z axis:

[image]

Give it and apply a *Subdivision Surface* modifier in order to smooth:

[image]

Test: Poles closer together:

[image]

After a bit of scale and *Subdivision Surface*:

[image]

Comment: I like it, is there a way to get the poles closer together?

Comment: sure, see my edit, you just need to move them with the Shrinkwrap on, when you're glad, apply the Shrinkwrap and scale and so on (well I guess you need to be careful with overlapping faces)

Comment: I was messing around with cast modifier -> sphere and moving it around in edit mode.  Seems to be workable in a pinch.

Comment: Yes I also thought about it but haven't tried. I've just edited, actually you don't need bevel, just a Subsurface, which reduces the chance to get overlapping faces I guess